# Manage Queue Members as a VisualForce page - is it possible?

Tags: apex, visualforce, leads

Due to recent security restrictions, our organization would like to remove the (very powerful) "Customize Application" permission from our operations users; however, these users actively manage our Queues for leads.

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a VisualForce / Apex Controller customization that would allow a user WITHOUT the "Customize Application" permission to manage Queue membership? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible, let's poke FinancialForce guys, maybe they'll shed some secrets ;) @AndrewFawcett, @PhilHawthorn? From what I remember you won't be able to modify any non-setup object in same operation or you'll be slapped with MIXED_DML_OPERATION error.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you can, one of our basic profiles doesn't have that enabled and its possible to do as a user with that profile (using our VF page). That being the case, can't see why you couldn't modify queue membership from your apex controller.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This seems to be possible. I just performed this simple test as a user without that permission without any problems, so if I understand the question correctly I think the answer is yes.

**Page:**

```
<apex:page controller="TestQueueMembership">

    <apex:messages />

    <apex:form >
        <apex:commandButton value="Test" action="{!toggle}"/>
    </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Controller:**

```
public class TestQueueMembership
{
    public PageReference toggle()
    {
        List<GroupMember> groups = [select Id from GroupMember where Group.Type = 'Queue' and GroupId = '00Gb0000000RFBC' and UserOrGroupId = '005b0000000TPaL'];
        if( !groups.isEmpty() )
        {
            delete groups;        
            ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Removed user from Queue') );
        }
        else
        {
            insert new GroupMember( GroupId = '00Gb0000000RFBC', UserOrGroupId = '005b0000000TPaL' ); 
            ApexPages.addMessage( new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.INFO, 'Added user to Queue') );
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Phil - this is fantastic! I appreciate you including some sample code as well to get us started. If you have code in the way of replicating the "Available" vs. "Selected" multi-select boxes that would be GREAT!

Comment: I don't I'm afraid, you can query the GroupMember object where `Group.Type = 'Queue'` for available and then the query I supplied above to get Selected